# How do I remove repeated and identical rows from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset with two many rows for my purpose, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it simple and usable. I have removed all of the columns that I do not need (for now) and removed all of the NA rows.

The data looks like this:

```
   SampleID   Score   Habitat  
   001-1         0     MCSHRU  
   001-2         1     MCSHRU  
   001-2         1     MCSHRU  
   001-2         1     MCSHRU  
   001-3         0       MCRU  
   001-4         3     MCSHRU  
   001-4         3     MCSHRU
```

Sample 001-2 has three entries, and they're all the same. This is because the original dataset had a row for each species found in each sample. I'm not interested in the species data and I just want to compare scores for each habitat.

I'd like to have just one row for each SampleID. I could take the mean or minimum for the Score data, but I'm not sure what to do with Habitat data because it is categorical.

**How can I clean out the repeated data rows so that there is only one row of data for each SampleID?**

It should look like this in the end:

```
  SampleID   Score   Habitat  
   001-1         0    MCSHRU  
   001-2         1    MCSHRU  
   001-3         0      MCRU  
   001-4         3    MCSHRU
```

Comment: `dplyr::distinct(df)` or if you have more columns `dplyr::distinct(df, SampleID, Score, MCSHRU, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `unique(df)` from `base` or  `distinct(df)` from `dplyr`

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast response! I used ```df2 <- df %>% distinct(SampleID, .keep_all = TRUE)``` and it worked perfectly.